# View not rendering from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

here's the thing. I have this view named "Testing":

```
   @model Project.Models.Test
   @{
    Layout = null;
    }

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <title>Testing</title>   
   </head>
   <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  --- some html and razor using model attributes ---

  }
  </body>
  </html>
```

And in TestController, the ActionResult method that should return the view.

```
    public ActionResult Testing(int id) {
        Test test = db.Test.Find(id); (I have a breakpoint in here)
        if (test == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(test);
    }
```

For some reason if I write on the address bar in the browser `localhost:(number of port)/Test/Testing/1` the view renders but not from the controller, because I have a breakpoint in the controller and it doesn't execute that instructions. Because of that, everything is null obviusly because there's no object. I don't know why the view is rendering without calling the controller action.

Edit: My routeconfig look like this

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually debugging? It's possible for the web server to be running and pages to load without debugging.

Comment: What if you change the action method to return a partial view instead (since your view is a partial view, i.e. `Layout = null;`), `return PartialView(test);`?  I don't think it should matter but maybe worth a shot.

Comment: Also, you may have a reason for doing this, but usually the root HTML markup goes in the Layout and in the Layout you use the razor statement `@RenderBody()` as a place holder for the view.

Comment: @JasonP I'm debugging, at least as far as I know.

Comment: I need a view for printing a credential, so I need it to be a white clean one. I will create a especial layout for this view and try.

Comment: Ah ok, figured there was probably a reason for your approach.

Comment: Creating a layout for this view, didn't change anything. I can't understand why the action in the controller is never called. Tricky one.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in your view, and entering `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]` in the Watch or Immediate Window

Comment: Are you using the default MVC behavior everywhere else, or do you have anything custom, like a Controller Factory?

Comment: I'm using default MVC behavior. @JasonP I tried what you told me, and view context returns "Test" the name of the right controller.

Comment: Hmm, this is bizarre.  So what exactly is null in your view?  I see you check for the model being null in the action method.

Comment: For example I have @Html.LabelFor(m => m.name) and the model is null, the problem is that never enters in the action method! Tricky tricky! LOL.

Comment: Ok, try creating a brand new MVC project and just adding the controller/action and view you posted here and see if it works.